# Why with SlugField model cannot be updated and without slugfield it can be updated?

Tags: django

In general, the data didn't change, I decided to remove the slug in the model and it all worked. Before that, when I changed something through the admin panel, and generally through any means nothing changed, but for some reason when I removed the slug field, any field changes. Why did it happen?

Models (BEFORE REMOVING)

```py
from .for_slug import slugify as my_slugify

class Quiz(models.Model):
    """Quiz model"""
    slug = models.SlugField('Url-адрес', max_length=50, blank=True)
    .....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Use the custom slugfiy (for_slug.py)"""
        if not self.slug:
            slug = my_slugify(self.title)
            exists = Quiz.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()

            if exists:
                slug += f'-{str(int(time()))}'

            self.slug = slug
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

for_slug.py

```py
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify as django_slugify

alphabet = {
    'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 'е': 'e',
    'ё': 'yo', 'ж': 'zh', 'з': 'z', 'и': 'i', 'й': 'j', 'к': 'k',
    'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n', 'о': 'o', 'п': 'p', 'р': 'r',
    'с': 's', 'т': 't', 'у': 'u', 'ф': 'f', 'х': 'kh', 'ц': 'ts',
    'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 'щ': 'shch', 'ы': 'i', 'э': 'e', 'ю': 'yu',
    'я': 'ya'
}


def slugify(s):
    return django_slugify(''.join(alphabet.get(w, w) for w in s.lower()))
```

If it matters I use PostgreSQL. Why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

**I solved that problem. In the method save() I just removed**

```py
if not self.slug:
```

And it worked.